# Successfully Navigating the DASD with Apple's Silent-Push Notifications

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

For Silent-Push Notifications (SPNs), Apple suggests sending no more that 2 Pushes per device per hour. If you exceed this limit, the client's DASD (*Duet Activity Scheduler Daemon*) may throttle future SPNs to the target app. The decision heuristic for this throttling is not well documented, perhaps intentionally. But since SPNs are required to be set with apns-priority=5 (non-immediate, non-guaranteed delivery) what is the ideal send rate for getting a successful delivery to the app?

For example, are chances of successfully navigating the DASD better by sending 2 SPNs/device per HOUR (until an ACK is received by our server) or are the chances better with only 2 SPNs/device per DAY?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks!